# restatement question

Tags: articles

In England, according to **a new law**, older people do not have to retire unless they are
mentally or physically incapable of working.

Is the sentence above can be a direct replacement for;

The new law in England allows older people to continue working as long as they are physically
or mentally able to work.

In the first sentence it says a new law,
in the second the new law.
(This is not a reading passage or something like that) I wonder they both have the same meaning or not.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you only asking about the difference between *a* and *the*? If so, it would be better if that were the *only* difference you had between the two sentences. The more you change things, the more everything adds up to an overall difference—that may or may not be related to one specific variable. (Also, you don't want people analyzing different parts of the sentences, if you don't care about those.)

Comment: Do you know the difference between England and the United Kingdom?

Comment: A law passed in 2011 isn't really "new".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I think, in this case, we can (potentially) help someone with their use of language without taking them to task on the facts. They could be working from tasks written seven years ago, and confusion on England/UK is hardly unusual (even here in the UK, sadly). However, that still requires the question to be a little clearer...

Comment: Actually, this is a multi-choice question. The first sentence is the sentence given as the in the question.

Comment: the second one is CHOICE D. THERE ARE FOUR MORE CHOICES A B C AND E

Comment: D is given as the correct choice which necessarily is a direct replacement for the first sentence or at least the question setter claims so.

Comment: "unless you can't go" is functionally equivalent to "as long as you can go". That's the main point the book is trying to show.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, English law is quite distinct from Scots law and Northern Irish Law, and therefore "a new law in England" is quite correct. The Welsh might decry the failure to say "English and Welsh law", but, whichever way you slice it, there is technically [no such thing as British or UK law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_United_Kingdom).

Comment: fred2, the UK Parliament makes laws for the whole nation. It only makes sense to single out "England" when a law does not include Wales Scotland, and Northern Ireland. The devolved assemblies have powers to make certain local legislation, but  the Employment Equality (Repeal of Retirement Age Provisions) Regulations 2011 have effect everywhere in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

When referring to a piece of legislation, without naming it, we would use the indefinite article 'a'. In 2011 we could have said "a new law abolishes default retirement age". If we wanted to be specific, and name the new law, we would use 'the': "The new law, called The Employment Equality (Repeal of Retirement Age Provisions) Regulations 2011, has abolished default retirement age."

**A** law made the fitting of seat belts in new cars compulsory in 1967.

Fitting seat belts in new cars was made compulsory by **the** Road Safety Act of 1967.